# Using bessel functions in MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, bessel-functions

I'm trying to put all of my functions from Excel workbook into MATLAB. I'm having an issue using bessel functions in MATLAB. I'm simply not getting the same results from MATLAB as I do in excel.

For example, in excel if I execute

```
=0.32*BESSELI(0.32,0)/2/BESSELI(0.32,1)
```

I get 1.012.

When I use the same approach in MATLAB

```
0.32*besseli(0.32,0)/2/besseli(0.32,1)
```

I simply get zero.

Can someone please help me integrate bessel functions into my MATLAB script so that they provide the same answer as they do when used in excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB and Excel have the arguments of the `besseli` function in a different order.

The following expression (note the order of arguments changed):

```
0.32*besseli(0, 0.32)/2/besseli(1, 0.32)
```

will yield:

```
> ans =  1.0127
```

in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besseli.html) shows the formulae and show that if you use Z=0, which you have in your first `besseli`, you should get 0, which you do. The second call to `besseli` should not get you zero, and indeed it does not:

[image]

```
besseli(0.32,1)
ans =
    1.0744
```

I copied the following from the aforementioned documentation:

[image]

This shows that *unless*  your nu (that Greek thing that looks like a v) is zero, your modified Bessel function of the first kind at Z=0 will be, in fact zero.
On a side note: why are you doubly dividing and not simply writing

```
0.32*besseli(0.32,0)*besseli(0.32,1)/2
```

Comment: I think they want `0.32*besseli(0.32,0)/(2*besseli(0.32,1))` not `0.32*besseli(0.32,0)*besseli(0.32,1)/2`.